# 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'fbind'

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, kivy

I'm trying to write a code that'll add NumPy arrays to widgets
here's my code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.button import Button
import numpy as np


class cell(Button):  # MAKING A BUTTON
    def __init__(self):
        Button.__init__(self)
        self.background_normal = 'button.jpg'

    def on_press(self):
        self.background_normal = 'onPress.jpg'


class graphics(GridLayout):

    def __init__(self):  # BUILDING GRAPHIC BOARD
        GridLayout.__init__(self)
        self.cols = 3
        self.rows = 3
        c = cell()
        my_image = Image(source='empty.jpg')
        emptySquareArray = np.array([[my_image, my_image], [my_image, my_image]])
        squareArray = np.array([[c, c], [c, c]])
        self.sq = np.array([[squareArray, squareArray, squareArray], # PLAYING BOARD
                            [squareArray, emptySquareArray, squareArray],
                            [squareArray, squareArray, squareArray]])
        for i in range(3):
            for j in range(3):
                self.add_widget(self.sq[i][j])
```

but I keep getting the error:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'fbind'
```

referring to the last line of code. i don't know what im doing wrong. thanks!

Comment: The `add_widget()` method expects a `Widget` as its argument. `self.sq` is a `numpy.ndarray`, not a `Widget`.

Comment: Just before the `add_widget()` call, do a `print(self.sq[i][j])` to see what you are trying to add.